# Arch with XFCE & SDDM: New user doesn't get a full desktop environment... Why?

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, useradd, sddm

**Intro**

Okay, this question was initially posted with hints that `/etc/skel` might be part of the issue. I have since removed the contents of `/etc/skel`, tried again and the issue still persists.

As I said in the initial post, I don't usually use multiple users on systems with graphical environments so I probably look like a total tool and I hope you can forgive the ignorance.

**The Problem**

When creating a new user using `useradd -m -G client newuser` I expect that user to login, through SDDM, and gain access to a graphical desktop environment just like the initial user can. However, when logging in with `newuser` it just drops to a non-graphical shell.

**The Question(s)**

Why is this happening to me? What have I missed?

I'll likely need to provide more info and config etc. Let me know where I should start.

**Edit 1: Couple of errors to keep you going**

When running `startx` after logging in as `newuser` I receive the following:

```
Only console users are allowed to run the X server
```

When running `startxfce4`:

```
X server already running on display 0:0

Another session manager is already running
```

This is despite logging in straight from boot so I know no other sessions are currently active.

**Edit 2: The exact issue and answer**

So, in all of my infinite wisdom I forgot to grep through the files for hardcoded filepaths.

There were loads. A monumental amount. Just about every file. Thanks to the link posted by C.W. below I remembered how to grep and sorted out the issue quickly with the following command:

```
cd /home/newuser && grep -rl 'testuser' . | xargs sed -i "s/testuser/newuser/g"
```

Is 10 a.m too early for a drink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have read your unedited post some hours ago and wasn't able to answer because i was at work. The solution for the cloned config files is maybe found [here](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=4168) at the xfce forums.

On your recent problem: Did you add `exec startxfce4` to a xinitrc-file at the user's home directory? In this case startx and xinit will execute it from there. Otherwise startx will run the default `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`.

Comment: The default xinitrc file is being called as you say. Just tried running both `startx` and `startxfce4` from the terminal and received the errors I've edited into the end of my post.

Comment: I'm trying so hard not to scream the bloody office down right now. It was so obvious. Will add the exact issue to the end of my question but it was somewhere in your link that got me through. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have forgotten to give the new user a /home.

```
useradd -m  -d  /home/newuser -G client newuser
```

and give him a password `passwd newuser`

Comment: -m gave it a home directory in the default location i.e. `/home/newuser`

Comment: It depends what is in `/etc/default/useradd`  I my case `# The default home directory. Same as DHOME for adduser
# HOME=/home` It is comment out, so I have to use the -d option.

Comment: Ah right, no bother.